# Can I run bitcoind without BerkeleyDB 4.8 installed?

Tags: bitcoind, compiling, library

I am using a CentOS server to build Bitcoin from source. After installing all of Bitcoin's dependancies on this build server, I have successfully built bitcoind and bitcoin-cli (the two binaries that I need). I then copy those binaries from the build server to the bitcoin server which of course is a fresh image of the CentOS. Now I'm wondering if I need to have BerkeleyDB 4.8 installed on the bitcoin server, or if I'm just not compiling/linking bitcoin properly.

The error as you would expect if BerkeleyDB 4.8 is not installed/linked properly:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libdb_cxx-4.8.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It was my assumption that I can install dependancies on one server, link and build bitcoin on that server, and then move the binaries to a server without scary build dependancies on it to run the binary in a clean environment. Someone please shed some wisdom on my lack thereof.

Comment: You can definitely compile with `./configure --disable-wallet` to avoid Berkley DB. Are you getting this error at compile or run time?

Comment: I'll need the wallet enabled so that is not an option. I'm getting the error at runtime. Berkeley DB is not installed however this article: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/4103 says that i can build Berkeley --with-static and that should compile BerkeleyDB4.8 into the bitcoin binary but it doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I feel stupid...

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md#berkeley-db

I followed that to the T and I got it working. Now I'm struggling with OpenSSL issues :/

Comment: make sure you got all the dependencies installed